# how to assign new groups to data column in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, datatable, conditional-statements

I have a list of data tables (df 1 and df2).
I would like to know how fix the sorting based on Type and Area infromation from data table.
For e.g. df1$type has 3 rows and df2$type 4 rows, where Bg is common element.
To avoid such confusion I am trying to assign each table a pre-defined group with new column.
The pre-defined groups G1 and G2 has higher area compared to the other avaialble elements in each   type. So i would like to know 1) what would be best approch to separate groups if  there is a overalp of 1-2 types 2) How I can also check if area of pre-defined group is higher compared to other Type elments in each table.

```
    df1<- data.frame(
          No=c(3, 3, 3),
          Type=c("Bg", "Ea", "Xg"), 
          Area=c(19, 5, 4)) 
    df2 <- data.frame(
         No=c(4, 4, 4, 4),
         Type=c("Bg", "Ra","Rm","Xg"), 
         Area=c(1, 10,  1, 20))
```

```
  # list of diffrent tables
```

```
       df.table <- list(df1,df2) # list of tables
```

```
        G1 <- c("Bg", "Ea", "Xg")
        G2 <- c("Ra","Xg")
```

```
 I tried
```

```
       for (j in 1:length(df.table )){
           grp <- as.data.frame(df.table[[j]])
           plot<- grp %>% mutate(Group=
                           case_when((Type %in% G1)&&(Area[(Type == G1)>(Type != G1)])~"G1"
                                    ,(Type %in% G2)&&(Area[(Type == G2)>(Type!= G2)])~"G2" 
                                    ,TRUE ~ "Other"
                               ))
          print(plot)                                                                  
         }
```

However, I get an output below. For No. 4 the Group should G2.

```
            No Type Area Group
            3   Bg   19    G1
            3   Ea    5    G1
            3   Xg    4    G1
            No Type Area Group
            4   Bg    1    G1
            4   Ra   10    G1
            4   Rm    1    G1
            4   Xg   20    G1
Expected output 
            No Type Area Group
            3   Bg   19    G1
            3   Ea    5    G1
            3   Xg    4    G1
            No Type Area Group
            4   Bg    1    G2
            4   Ra   10    G2
            4   Rm    1    G2
            4   Xg   20    G2
     Thanks
```

Comment: Its common element in both G1 and G2. This is what I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, let me try. G1 and G2 are known conditions which needs to compared in and in output allocate as new column. In this example, df1$Type  has all  types same to G1. But df2$Type has only two types specied G2 and has other two which not match. 1. test must check if  it matches with pre-defined groups (G1 and G2) then 2. check if area of these type is higher than other Types (If there are any). But my test fails with coomon element (e.g. Xg) in both. Please let me know if its not clear.

Comment: @AnilGoyal: The G1 and G2 I showed here are just an examples of conditions where my test fails. The data set is large with hundreds of tables and possibly 8-10 Gs. The Gs are predefined criteria based larger area. In above example G1 needs to be in the group where Bg, Ea and Xg are present together and likely will have higher area compared to others (if there are any). However, G2 only Ra (new) and Xg (also present in df1$Type) are present together and likely will have higher area compared to others (Here Bg is very less area).

Comment: I think, first check if df1$Type has all elements defined in G1 if yes then check area is greater than other available elements. In df2$Type check if its matches with G1 or G2 (its G2 test condition) and then check area if Xg and Ra is greater than Bg and Rm. If yes, then it will group 2. clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231974/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-uday).